# Bootstrap: How to make columns wrap @ 1024px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make columns wrap ***EVEN*** at 1024px? Because, (@ 1024px) the page ***IS*** responsive, but the *"stretchiness"* is ugly.

Comment: The embeddeded result: http://jsfiddle.net/pkdsleeper/ZJJFJ/embedded/result/ I hate to break it to you, but your page isn't loading at all correctly on Chrome. The top part of the page is not visible at all (only about half the arrows can be seen and below).

Comment: Also, what is it you're wanting to do? If you don't want to have columns, why not *not* use `span6, span3 and span3`? Or do you want a `max-width` so the columns stop growing in width?

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thx for replying. 1. I only loaded that row. If that is what you mean by "broken", I was only isolating on the code I wished uto update. 2. Want I want is that at 1024px... i.e. mobile in landscape (kindle Fire, etc.), the coloumns should stack. Like they do at smaller screen sizes.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, Based on what I coded (only one row), looks right in chrome to me (win7/64, Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 m)

Comment: Ok, I see; you want it to respond then revert at a certain size. Hmm. (And I've got the same setup, Win7 64 and Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79. If it's not your full code, then I wouldn't worry about it.)

Comment: You can use the same method Bootstrap uses to force the `span#` elements to stretch to `100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZJJFJ/1/ Note, you'll need to compensate for some of the other effects of doing this.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Your css looks promising... checking.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - With some fiddling that should work!

Comment: @Jared Farrish you might want to add an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level, you can [mimic the Bootstrap method](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less#L59):

```
//
// Responsive: Landscape phone to desktop/tablet
// --------------------------------------------------
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  // GRID & CONTAINERS
  // -----------------
  // Remove width from containers
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }

  // Fluid rows
  .row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
  }

  // Make all grid-sized elements block level again
  [class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    .box-sizing(border-box);
  }
  .span12,
  .row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    .box-sizing(border-box);
  }
}
```

Which of course is [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/). This is the compiled LESS:

```
[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is a small snippet that begins the task of replicating this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
    [class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZJJFJ/1/

There's also a [responsive CSS file for greater than 1200px](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-1200px-min.less), which may also be helpful. If you do this with LESS, I'm sure it will be simpler as well, instead of pure CSS.

Comment: It works! You Sir, are a gentleman and a scholar :) And YES to LESS... I'm a LESS fanboy! Thank you for your assistance.